# My first R shiny app - my plot does not show

Tags: r, shiny

I have a complex functions that works so far. I need to make this function available for non-programmers at work and I started to create a simple App.

The problem is that within my user-defined-function I create a graphic that is stored as an object, as well as the final output is stored as data frame and then returned. All important results become exported later on. All this works fine.
But I would like to have my final graphic plotted within R shiny.

I tried to bring a little example with which I still struggle

```
    test_function <- function(x){
  new_data <- iris[iris$Species==x,] %>% droplevels()
  write.csv(new_data,"test.csv")
  new_plot <- plot(new_data$Sepal.Length,new_data$Petal.Length)
  new_plot %>% plot
  return(new_data)
} # I would run my code outside the app, I would see the plots in my Rstudio plot panel.

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Test for 2022"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("Species",
                "Insert species name"),
      actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Run")
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$input_action, {
    taxa <- input$Species
    test_function(taxa)
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(test_function(input$Species))})
  })
}
```

shinyApp(ui, server) # But here no graphics, code runs,.. everything exported as wished. What do I need to change so that I get a new plot anytime I change the input name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return a plot rather than a data frame

Your server logic is simpler if your function returns a plot, and you can just call `renderPlot()` on it.

```r
test_function <- function(x) {
    new_data <- iris[iris$Species == x, ] %>% droplevels()
    plot(new_data$Sepal.Length, new_data$Petal.Length)
}
```

That way your server can just render the output of that function.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$input_action, {
        output$plot <- renderPlot(test_function(input$Species))
    })
}
```

I haven't changed the `ui` so I haven't included it here, just the server logic and the function's return value. However, I would recommend changing it as it makes the server logic simpler, and it's probably easier for users as well.

#### Use a `selectInput()`

Currently you need your `observeEvent()` and a Run button because your text box is empty when the application loads. However, your logic will be even simpler if you use a `selectInput()`, i.e. a drop down box, particularly if it has a default value.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Species", label = "Select species", choices = unique(iris$Species), selected = unique(iris$Species[1])),
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot(test_function(input$Species))
}
```

You no longer need the `observeEvent()` in your logic, and your server code is literally one line. Also your UI is cleaner as you don't need a run button, and you don't need to introduce logic to deal with users entering invalid or malicious input into the text box.

#### Output

##### With text box and run button

[image]

##### With drop down box

[image]

Comment: The dropdown box is very helpful